# POST method not sending data to mongodb

Tags: typescript, mongodb, express, post

I'm creating a MERN app, I created the backend and wanted to test it with the REST client vscode extension. Like this:

```
`POST http://localhost:4000/signup
Content-Type: application/json

{
    "email": "something@gmail.com",
    "username": "something",
    "password": "something"
}`
```

and it returns 200 OK but no data is sent to MongoDB.
this is what I get from the test above:

```
    HTTP/1.1 200 OK
X-Powered-By: Express
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 2
ETag: W/"2-vyGp6PvFo4RvsFtPoIWeCReyIC8"
Date: Fri, 14 May 2021 06:51:53 GMT
Connection: close

{}
```

this is the server.ts file:

```
import express from "express";
import * as dotenv from "dotenv";
import mongoose from "mongoose";
import endpointsConfig from "./endpoints.config";
import routerUrls from "./routes/router";
import cors from "cors";
dotenv.config();
const app = express();
//database connection
mongoose.connect(endpointsConfig.DataBaseUrl, { useNewUrlParser: true }, () => {
  console.log("database connection is success");
});
app.use(express.json());
app.use(cors());
//base path
app.use("/", routerUrls);
app.listen(4000, () => console.log("server is up and running on port 4000"));
```

router.ts file:

```
import express from "express";
import mongooseModel from "../models/mongooseModel";

const router = express.Router();

type UserData = {
  email: string;
  username: string;
  password: string;
};

router.post("/signup", (req, res) => {
  const signupUser = new mongooseModel({
    email: req.body.email,
    username: req.body.username,
    password: req.body.password,
  });

  signupUser
    .save()
    .then((data: UserData) => {
      res.json(data);
    })
    .catch((error: string) => {
      res.json(error);
    });
});

export default router;
```

and mongooseModel:

```
import mongoose from "mongoose";

const signupTemplate = new mongoose.Schema({
  email: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  username: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  password: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  date: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now,
  },
});

const mongooseModel = mongoose.model("usertable", signupTemplate);

export default mongooseModel;
```

from the MongoDB cloud dashboard I see that the connection is good, but don't get what's wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The codes doe not have any problems. More likely the connection string is wrong.

Can you add the err params in the callback to see if there is any thing printed out.

```
mongoose.connect(endpointsConfig.DataBaseUrl, { useNewUrlParser: true }, (err) => {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err)
    } else {
        console.log("database connection is success");
    }
});
```

Comment: You were right, the problem was with the connection string to be more precise with the way I loaded the .env variable. Thank you